# Border doesn't inherit Control, so how does a setter on Control.Background work?

Tags: .net, wpf, inheritance, border, controls

Since Border doesn't derive from Control, how does this work ?

```
    <Border.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Background` dependency property in WPF is shared by many classes. It is defined in the `Panel` class, other classes just call `AddOwner` on it.

**Border.cs**

```
[CommonDependencyProperty]
public static readonly DependencyProperty BackgroundProperty =
    Panel.BackgroundProperty.AddOwner(
        typeof (Border),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender |
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.SubPropertiesDoNotAffectRender));
```

**Panel.cs**

```
[CommonDependencyProperty] 
public static readonly DependencyProperty BackgroundProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Background", 
        typeof(Brush),
        typeof(Panel),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((Brush)null,
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender | 
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.SubPropertiesDoNotAffectRender));
```

Comment: @franssu There's no magic, I've just decompiled `Border` class using Resharper (there're also Reflector and other decompilers). .NET Framework Sources also work... from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

Class `Control` that can interact with the user. This includes classes: `TextBox`, `Button`, etc. Quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.aspx):

> The Control class is the base class for many of the controls you add to an application. The Control class defines very little behavior; while it is possible to add a Control to your application, it is far more common to add a control that inherits from Control, such as a Button or ListBox.

He also adds a dependency property, such as `Background`, `FontFamily`, `Foreground`, etc., which are available all the controls that are in `System.Windows.Controls`. A complete list of properties is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.aspx). He also represents the base class for user interface (UI) elements that use a `ControlTemplate` to define their appearance.

Let's look at the inheritance hierarchy on the `Border`, link on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.border.aspx):

```
System.Object 
 System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherObject
  System.Windows.DependencyObject
   System.Windows.Media.Visual
    System.Windows.UIElement
     System.Windows.FrameworkElement
      System.Windows.Controls.Decorator
       System.Windows.Controls.Border
```

It in `System.Windows.Controls`, therefore, it inherits all the properties that are available to `Control`.

Comment: "It in System.Windows.Controls, therefore, it inherits all the properties that are available to Control." 

Why ?

Comment: @franssu: In `WinForms` for example, each visual component called a `Control`. In WPF is not. For example, the `Panel` is not an control but it has properties that are inherited from the `Control` class. This leads to a little confusion. In the hierarchy shown that `Border` derives directly from the `FrameworkElement`, but it does not have such properties as the `Background`, `FontFamily`. Consequently, all the elements found in `System.Windows.Controls`, implicitly or explicitly, inherit the properties available in `Control` class.

Comment: Thank you, but how did you find that out ? Is it written anywhere on the MSDN ? Is that a standard practice ?

Comment: @franssu: About the comment, basically, in the book `Matthew MacDonald: Pro WPF in C#` [link](http://www.amazon.com/Pro-WPF-2010-Presentation-Foundation/dp/1430272058), in the very first chapters. I advise them to read, a very good book.